# Amplify API subscription failing authorization

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a React application that currently uses Amplify GraphQL APIs.  I have set those APIs up so that they require using Cognito user pools for authorization.  For example the following code is successfully retrieving a list of values from my Projects collection in DynamoDB

```
const apiData = await API.graphql({ query: listProjects, authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"  });
```

Recently I have been trying to setup a subscription so that I can receive real time updates from AppSync when new entries are added to my Projects collection.  This is the code that I am trying to get to work:

```
const subscription = API.graphql({query: subscriptions.onUpdateProject, authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"}
    ).subscribe({
    next: ({ provider, value }) => console.log({ provider, value }),
    error: error => console.warn(error)
});
```

Unfortunately, this code is failing when executed, it is causing this error to be raised:

```
"Connection failed: {\"errors\":[{\"errorType\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"Not Authorized to access onUpdateProject on type Project\"}]}"
```

I am not quite sure how to troubleshoot this or resolve it, do subscriptions require a special configuration with respect to authorization?  Are Cognito user pools supported with subscriptions?  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the a variable to specify the owner to my subscription as shown below.   I found this in another issue (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/456).

```
        const updateProjectSubscription = API.graphql({query: subscriptions.onUpdateProject, authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS', variables: {
            owner: Auth.user.attributes.sub 
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - adding the `AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH` to the config:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/js/#configure-multiple-authorization-types

```
import { Amplify, AuthModeStrategyType } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'; 

Amplify.configure({
  ...awsconfig,
  DataStore: {
    authModeStrategyType: AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH
  }
})
```